# Problems getting Tiles work with Struts2

Tags: struts, struts-config

I'm using struts 2.2.1 and tiles 2.2.2. I've done every step described [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-47) but I cannot get tiles work... I get the following error while deploying my war to glassfish 3.1:

```
[#|2011-10-04T08:43:28.117+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=74;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:130)
```

In my WEB-INF/lib I've got commons-collections-3.1.jar, commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar, struts2-core-2.2.1.jar, tiles-api-2.2.2.jar, tiles-core-2.2.2.jar, tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar and xwork-core-2.2.1.jar.

This is my struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="appDefault">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
                    <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
                    <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="appDefault" />

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>

        <global-results>
            <result name="exception">/jsp/exceptions/exception.jsp</result>
            <result name="webServiceException">/jsp/exceptions/webserviceexception.jsp</result>
        </global-results>

        <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception" />
        <exception-mapping exception="java.io.IOException" result="exception" />
        <exception-mapping exception="exceptions.WebServiceExceptionForStruts"
                result="webServiceException" />
        </global-exception-mappings>

        <action name="tilesTest" class="test.action.TilesTest">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/welcome.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="index">
            <result>/jsp/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

After inserting the code into my struts.xml, I get this error in eclipse:

[image]

And this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Consumer</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>

    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the S2 tiles plugin. It's listed in the referenced article.

Your second issue with the XML is clearly stated in the IDE error; the order of elements given in the error message isn't the order you define the elements in your XML file.

Comment: I've added the struts2-tiles-plugin-2.2.1.jar and corrected the order in the struts.xml. The IDE-error is gone, but the ClassDefNotFound is still there (now at another point): [#|2011-10-04T23:39:35.690+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/web/startup/TilesListener
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5271)

Comment: My first assumption would be to actually check the [tiles version used by the S2 tiles plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-tiles-plugin/2.2.1). That'd lead me to believe you're mixing-and-matching incompatible versions.

Comment: Nice one :-) The dependencies were the "evil part". But there are A LOT of dependencies... I'll have a look at maven ^^ Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException, looks like missing jar issue. Can you see the tiles plugin jar in war that is getting deployed on glassfish server.if not check check the war creation setting in you IDE. We faced this problem when it was not pushing jars from lib to the war.

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException Always alerts you that some class/jar which is referenced is missing. Make sure you have all the basic jars required for tiles.

In my case, I have these jars (besides struts2 jars) in my struts2 application to test a demo tile project.

- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-digester-2.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
- ognl-3.0.1.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar
- struts2-tiles-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar
- tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
- tiles-compat-2.2.2.jar
- tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
- tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
- tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
- tiles-template-2.2.2.jar

Best of luck.

Regards,
Amir Ali